# Calculate the linear regression for several files?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have 3 files (matrix with 200 columns and 6 rows) in one folder

```
mat1 <- matrix(seq(1:1200), ncol = 200)
mat2 <- matrix(seq(1:1200), ncol = 200)
mat3 <- matrix(seq(1:1200), ncol = 200)
```

I have another 3 files (matrix with 200 columns and 6 rows) in another folder

```
at1 <- matrix(seq(1:1200), ncol = 200)
at2 <- matrix(seq(1:1200), ncol = 200)
at3 <- matrix(seq(1:1200), ncol = 200)
```

I would like to compute the linear regression equation:

```
mat=a + b * at
```

we, for instance, take the first pixel in

```
mat1[1,1]........until mat3[1,1]  and regress this with 
at1[1,1]........until at3[1,1]
```

and then write the output (the intercept and b coefficient....)

do the same with:

```
mat1[1,2]........until mat3[1,2]  and regress this with 
at1[1,2]........until at3[1,2]
```

So for each pixel in mat1, I will have intercept and coefficient b 
finally will get a matrix of intercept and a matrix of b coefficient.

I know that for only one simple matrix we use:

```
model=lm(mat1~at1)
```

But for temporal data I do not know. Any idea?

Comment: You really want to calculate 6*200 = 1200 separate linear regressions? It's easy enough with `sapply` or a `for` loop, but that's an odd task.  Please verify.

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday here (now deleted)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076785/calculate-the-linear-regression-for-several-files

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start:

```
myfits<-list()

for (j in 1:600) {
   for(k in 1:6) {
       ins <- c(at1[k,j],at2[k,j],at3[k,j])
       outs <- c(mat1[k,j],mat2[k,j],mat3[k,j])
       lmfit <-lm(outs~ins)
       myfits[[( k + (j-1)*6)]]<-lmfit
       }
   }
```

That will give you a list of all the linfits; you can then extract the coefficients (`list[[n]]$coefficients`) in a similar loop.  There are more compact ways to do this but I wanted to make it clear what's happening.

Comment: @sacvf you have to do a **little** thinking on your own.  I threw "n" in there as a placeholder index.  Do you understand what a list variable is?   And if the subscript is out of bounds, then clearly your `at1` matrix doesn't have as many rows or columns as in the example.  Try to find what's wrong on your own!

Comment: Yes, there are ways to collect the `[k,j]` element of all objects in some collection.  Take a look at `?ls` and `?get` .